# Bootstrap stand alone nav icon bar / toggle button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want the button with the three lines as a stand alone over an carousel image to save the place. Opening the toggle button should display the menu as usual.
This is my navigation with the whole navbar-stripe shown.

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="index.html">page 0</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="...">page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="....">page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any easy possibilities? Just tought about making the navbar full transparent.
Found this [codepen](https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/oCBxz). But maybe there's a better, more bootstrap-native alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "navbar-fixed-top" class in the nav, this will stick your nav on top and then using custom css make it transparent. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but the navigation shouldn't be fixed on top. I will try to make the carousel "under" the nav and make the nav transparent

Comment: i got it now ;) but instead of pushing down the content by navbar collapse, i want it overflown. Any hints?

Comment: A: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403923/make-bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-overlay-page